# can a hacker call constructor() function after deploy if it is public?

Tags: solidity, constructor

Is below function can be called by a hacker after deploy

```
constructor() public
{
    test = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A `constructor` is special.

It is executed on deployment but the bytecode isn't deployed to the contract address, so it can't be run again.

Hope it helps.